# CouchDB: Workflow for creating documents?

Tags: couchdb

Beginner question.

My goal is to add documents to my CouchDB database on a remote server.

Is this the a good way?

1. Create CouchDB documents using a code editor and store them on my hard drive.
2. Post them to my CouchDB database on a remote server.

If yes, how to do #2 on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using your browser, and use the Futon web app, which all CouchDB servers support. Just go to `/_utils/` in your browser and you can get started adding and modifying documents.

Once you are comfortable, I suggest the `curl` tool, however keep in mind that Windows is a little different from the examples.

In Linux and Mac, curl looks like this

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/db/ -d '{"_id":"something"}'
```

In Windows, you cannot use the single-quote:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/db/ -d "{\"_id\":\"something\"}"
```